# Checking if there exists a buffer whose name starting with a particular string

Tags: buffers

According to the documentation the function **get-buffer** checks if there is a buffer with a specific name. More precisely

```
(get-buffer name)
```

Return the buffer named name (a string).
If there is no live buffer named name, return nil. See the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/586753/) on stackoverflow.

Is there a similar way to check if there exists a buffer whose name starting with a specific string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function **`try-completion`** tests whether a given string can be completed against a given set of completions (e.g. strings).

Function **`buffer-list`** provides the list of buffers.

Function **`buffer-name`** returns the name of a given buffer.

```el
(defun matches-a-buffer-name? (name)
  "Return non-nil if NAME matches the name of an existing buffer."
  (try-completion name (mapcar #'buffer-name (buffer-list))))
```

`try-completion` also accepts an optional `PREDICATE` argument, which you can use to impose a particular kind of testing, e.g., a particular kind of matching.

`C-h f try-completion` tells you, part:

> Return common substring of all completions of `STRING` in `COLLECTION`.
>   Test each possible completion specified by `COLLECTION`
>   to see if it begins with `STRING`.  The possible completions may be
>   strings or symbols.  Symbols are converted to strings before testing,
>   see `symbol-name`.
>
> All that match `STRING` are compared together; the longest initial sequence
>   common to all these matches is the return value.
>   If there is no match at all, the return value is `nil`.
>   For a unique match which is exact, the return value is `t`.

Comment: Finally I decided to accept this answer because it also works for the versions <25.1. But the solution provided by xuchunyang is also very good.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `buffer-list` function to get a list of all buffers:

> (buffer-list &optional FRAME)
>
> Return a list of all existing live buffers.
>   If the optional arg FRAME is a frame, we return the buffer list in the
>   proper order for that frame: the buffers show in FRAME come first,
>   followed by the rest of the buffers.

So for example, one can use this to get a list of buffers whose name is starting with `*Minibuf-`, or `nil` if no such buffer exists:

```el
(seq-filter (lambda (buf) (string-prefix-p " *Minibuf-" (buffer-name buf)))
            (buffer-list))
     => (#<buffer  *Minibuf-1*> #<buffer  *Minibuf-0*>)
```

Comment: What is `seq-filter`?

Comment: @Name Search the function name in Emacs Lisp manual to read info about it: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sequence-Functions.html. It's provided by seq.el, which is part of Emacs since 25.1. It's also possible to install it as a package from GNU ELPA.